# Stationary point for a function

Tags: calculus

Find the value of k if $$\frac{x}{\left [ (x+1)^2(x-k) \right ]} $$ has a stationary point.

I've no idea to find the k. Should I differentiate it first?

Answer (score 1):

Use the quotient rule to differentiate the function $f$.

$$f(x) = \frac{g(x)}{h(x)} = \frac{x}{\left [ (x+1)^2(x-k) \right ]}$$

You can expand the denominator, then calculate $h'(x)$ as needed, or else use the product rule to find $h'(x)$.

$$f'(x) = \frac{g'(x) h(x) - g(x)h'(x)}{(h(x))^2}\tag{quotient rule}$$

Then set $f'(x) = 0$ (if $f(x)$ has a critical point, there exists an $x_c$ such that $f'(x_c) = 0). $  Use this fact to determine which value(s) $k$ can take on for the function and its derivative to be defined, and such that $f'(x) = 0$.

Comment: I got k(x-1)-2x^2=0 . How to know that which value of k can take in for the function ?

Comment: I think you need to differentiate again.

Comment: Can you show me for the solution of the f'(x)? @amWhy

Comment: $ k - 4 x = 0 , x = k/4 $ so if 50 values of k are given there are 50 solutions.

Answer (score 0):

If you are given a fraction to find maximum or minimum it is often useful to use the Quotient Rule.The  $ u/v $ form gives condition:

$$ \dfrac {u}{v} = \dfrac {u^{'}}{v^{'}} $$

$$ \dfrac {x}{x^3 +x^2(2-k)+x(1-2 k) -k} = \dfrac {1}{ 3 x^2 + 2 x (2-k) + (1-2 k) } $$

It leads to a cubic on simplification with three roots.If numerical k value is given at beginning, real roots can be found out.Else the roots can be found out by Cardano's formula (for roots of a cubic) in terms of $k$.